# PDO query for BLOB giving broken image

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I know this has been asked on here a few times, but could not figure out how to fix this based on the other questions.

I am trying to display all images from a table in a MySQL database. The images have all been successfully stored as BLOB. The `image_type` is also stored properly as either `image/jpeg` or `image/png`  However, when trying to display the images, it just returns a single broken image icon. When I remove the header, it displays a bunch of characters. I am pretty new to using PDO and have never worked with images in a database before. Any help would be much appreciated.

#### Here is the code to display the images

```
<?php
 /*** connect to the database ***/
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", 'user', 'pass');

  /*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  /*** The sql statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM images";

  /*** prepare the sql ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

  /*** exceute the query ***/
    $stmt->execute(); 

  /*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  /*** set the header for the image ***/
    $array = $stmt->fetch();

  /*** check we have a single image and type ***/
    if(sizeof($array) == 2) {
    /*** set the headers and display the image ***/
      header("Content-type: ".$array['image_type']);

    /*** output the image ***/
      echo $array['image'];
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Out of bounds Error");
    }
?>
```

Comment: do u get the correct content-type header? or is it all a "bunch of characters". Also if PDO is anything like the OCI8 ext, when you load a blob you need to access it as an object `echo $array['image']->load();` although i'm not 100% sure that will work. You could do it like this http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Working-With-BLOBs-P554.html and use bind vars to extract the blob

Comment: @mic it is a bunch of characters when I remove the header. I.E. ÿØÿàJFIFÿáXExifMM*‡i& ÿÛC       ÿÛCÿÀ"ÿÄ  ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚  %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwx

and it just keeps going (it is querying several images).

Comment: @mic I went through the tutorial you linked for retrieving. This did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: np glad u figured it out :)